# Storing API search results in local database

Tags: database, cookies, tracking, nodejs-server

Every time someone hits an API route I want to store that information in database, connected with req. IP.
Afther I would like to find some association rules based on similar searches. 
Should I store some information in cookies or to use local dartabase?

Example on some hotels site:
I want to store info that i got a lot of request for cheap hotels in some specific area.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely in a database. Cookies wouldn't make sense because

- You cannot rely on cookies for persistent data. They can expire, be cleared, etc.
- Cookies can hold a very limited amount of data (4093 bytes usually)
- Cookies are stored locally on your client's browser, you want information across all of your clients.

Tracking user behavior data is very common web feature. You may want to use a web analytics service such as [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) rather then implement your own.